# try out PyDrive in windows desktop

Tags: python, pydrive

I am following [this](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/) to learn how to use PyDrive library

I installed PyDrive at  `....PycharmProjects\Qt\venv\Lib\site-packages`
I copied code and saved it in  `c:\users\me\test.py`

Now I am stuck at how to run it. I have google drive account already with some files stored.

I need simple  steps to run it from command prompt or Idle or PyCharm
Do I need Google cloud account or any thing else?

I changed to (venv)c:\user\me\test.py

I get

```
ERROR  File "..\PycharmProjects\Qt\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\clientsecrets.py", line 121, in _loadfile
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets.json'
```

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello.txt'})
file1.SetContentString('Hello')
file1.Upload() 


docsfile.GetContentFile('test.html', mimetype='text/html')
```

Comment: What do you mean "changed drives"? Are you activating the `Qt/venv`?? Can you not run the script directly from PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PyDrive` is deprecated in favor of `PyDrive2` (`pip install PyDrive2`)

All Google SDKs require an auth token, and you can [refer to the documentation on how to generate one](https://iterative.github.io/PyDrive2/docs/build/html/quickstart.html#authentication) and where to create a JSON file (in your working directory) that is read by the library

Also be sure to read the [official Google Drive Python API page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

Comment: thanks OneCritekeer will try it and come back.

Comment: I give up the idea. Now I want some help to close my account in google cloud because I am sure i will forget and later be charged.